# How to determine which IAP was purchased?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm writing some code in swift for handling an IAP. How do you determine which IAP was purchased inside the the `paymentQueue` function?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)    {

    println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                println("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Restored:
                println("Product Restored");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                // case .Restored:
                //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SKPaymentTransaction` instance's `payment` property's `productIdentifier` value gives you the related product.

Comment: @holex Of course! I was using transaction instead of trans. Therefore productIdentifier doesn't show up. Still new to Swift. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, as you wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SKPaymentTransaction` instance's `payment` property's `productIdentifier` value gives you the related product.

---

you can read more about `SKPaymentTransaction` in [its Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction).

Answer (score 1):

From the transaction, you can get the payment, which contains the productIdentifier.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/SKPayment